# Restart build based on specific failure

Tags: teamcity

I have a CI/CD build that needs to compile some code using a licensed compiler. Sometimes there aren't enough licenses to go around and the compiler fails.

Is there a way to detect this error in the log and automatically restart the build? There is an option to trigger a build on failure, but I would like to trigger a build on this specific failure, as opposed to a general compile error.

TeamCity Enterprise 2023.05 (build 129203)